# how to change the color of an element on mouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a column of anchor tags, these have a class where a light blue color is define.

I made function, so when the mouse is over on any of the anchor elements some image link to the anchor tag is shown.

And now I would like to add to the anchor tag that is selected, a different color. So the user can see where in the column the image is linked. More for a reference to the user.

I added a class to with the different color on the mouseover function, but that didn't work. So I would like to know if you have any suggestions how to solve this.

I have a function for building the anchor tags and where I add the original color to them:

```
for (i=0; i<numberOf; i++) {
        var param2Slider = document.createElement("a");
        param2Slider.id = 'sliderAnchor_'+i;
        sliderAnchorId = param2Slider.id;
        param2Slider.name = 'param2Slider';
        param2Slider.className = 'nav2Slider';
        document.getElementById('nav2Slider').appendChild(param2Slider);
    }
```

And my function with the mouseover action:

```
function navigator2Slider(flatParam, directionParam) {

$('.nav2Slider').on('mouseover', function () {
    //$(this).attr('style').color='#29378F';
    nav2SliderName =  $(this).attr('id');
    nav2Id = nav2SliderName.split("_").pop();
    nav2Index = parseInt(nav2Id);
        $('#'+flatParam+'Stream').cycle(nav2Index);
        $('#'+directionParam+'Stream').cycle(nav2Index);            
});
```

}

I tried to add the new color on both functions, but my first problem is that even is added to the first anchor tag, the color is not displayed. And second, I want the color to be with the selected anchor tag, so I think it should be added on the mouserover function.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.css` to set the colour:

```
$(this).css('background-color', '#29378F');
```

As a sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/qVNen/

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: or maybe class? `$(this).addClass("new_colour")`

Comment: @Probandot can you post your code in a JS Fiddle? I provided an example showing how to change the background colour on mouseover.

Comment: @DarrenDavies here is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/todos27/Tr3yR/ Sorry, I think I'm missing some code. Let me try to add it. Is first time I'm using JS Fiddle on my own.

Comment: @DarrenDavies it worked when I used the tag id, instead of the class ;) Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Probandot - great :-) and no problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to make some style changes to the css on hover, why not use [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3ahover)

```
a:hover{
  /* insert your css changes */
}
```

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user designates an
>   element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/3HzT4/)**